# Designing according to various resolution in windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my metro application i want to design the pages that satisfy for all resolutions. For that i used the Viewbox control and set the height=768 and width=1366 for the control inside the Viewbox.In this case the design is satisfied for all resolution except 1024*768 and 1280*800.
How can I design the pages that satisfy for every resolution.Please help me?

Comment: You can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx) post form Microsoft that gives you all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

hi heres the code piece that will solve ur issue.

```
//add event listner on size changed
Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
```

here's the code inside the event listener or any other custom method where you would like to get the height and width and do all the stuff :

```
var height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
var width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

this will give you the height and width of the app. (I write app here because a metro can run also in snapped mode) ... According to this then you can do all manipulations with your controls.